# description: paragraph as definition - get straight left margin for multi-line definition

Tags: lists, indentation, description

With `\item[keyword]explanation-that-goes-on-for-several-lines` I get:

```
keyword this is the first line
    this is the second line
```

But I'd like it like this

```
keyword this is the first line
        this is the second line
```

I also tried with tabular, but then it didn't do line breaks at all!

Comment: i haven't got time to test it now, but it seems to me that (assuming you have multiple definitions) you could pick the longest term being defined and apply `\settowidth` to determine the magnitude of the indent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that `\labelwidth` is large enough to contain the widest label in the list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{list}{}{}
\item[keyword that is much too long] The quick brown fox jumps over
  the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick
  brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{list}
%
\begin{list}{}{\setlength\labelwidth{5cm}\setlength\leftmargin{5cm}\advance\leftmargin by \labelsep}
\item[keyword that is much too long] The quick brown fox jumps over
  the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick
  brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{list}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That almost did it, only now keywords are right align.

Comment: You can left align them by changing the definition of `\makelabel`. Try putting `\renewcommand\makelabel[1]{#1\hfil}` in the list declarations.

Comment: Well, well, well, you are the MAN!